# FORM authentication fallback in Wildfly 11

Tags: jsf, active-directory, wildfly, spnego

I currently have a working SPNEGO-configuration to login with a kerberos ticket. Now I want to fallback to FORM-based authentication using j_security_check and authenticate username/password against AD/LDAP.

If I set `<auth-method>SPNEGO,FORM</auth-method>` I'm redirected to the login page. Now I have no idee how to proceed from here?
Do I need a bean at all for my login form or are the values passed to the server automatically?
What configuration is needed in the standalone.xml?

Any help is highly appreciated. Using Wildfly 11.

My current configuration:

**web.xml**

```
 <security-constraint>
    <display-name>Security Constraint on Conversation</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>MyApp</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>

  <login-config>
    <auth-method>SPNEGO</auth-method>
    <realm-name>SPNEGO</realm-name>
  </login-config>

  <security-role>
    <description>Role required to log in to the Application</description>
    <role-name>*</role-name>
  </security-role>
```

**jboss-web.xml**

```
<jboss-web version="8.0" xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/schema/jbossas/jboss-web_8_0.xsd">
  <context-root>/MyApp</context-root>
  <default-encoding>UTF-8</default-encoding>
 <security-domain>SPNEGO</security-domain>
  <jacc-star-role-allow>true</jacc-star-role-allow>
</jboss-web>
```

**standalone.xml**

```
<security-domain name="SPNEGO" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="SPNEGO" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="serverSecurityDomain" value="host"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="host" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="Kerberos" flag="required" module="org.jboss.security.negotiation">
                            <module-option name="refreshKrb5Config" value="true"/>
                            <module-option name="doNotPrompt" value="true"/>
                            <module-option name="useKeyTab" value="true"/>
                            <module-option name="keyTab" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/wildfly.keytab"/>
                            <module-option name="storeKey" value="true"/>
                            <module-option name="principal" value="HTTP/me.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM"/>
                            <module-option name="debug" value="true"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
```

**login.xhtml**

```
 <form method="post" action="j_security_check">
            <h:form prependId="false" >
                <h:outputText value="Username"/>
                <p:password id="j_username" value="#{login.username}" />
                <p/>
                <h:outputText value="Passwort"/>
                <p:password id="j_password" value="#{login.password}" />
                <p/>
                <p:commandButton ajax="false" value="Login" action="#{login.login()}" />
            </h:form>
        </form>
```

Comment: If you use a login form like that, it is effectively not a 'jsf' form anymore. A plain html form for form login wpuld be 'identical'. Did you try that? No? Please do

Comment: @Kukeltje: yes, this question is about the necessary wildfly configuration

Answer (score 0):

Haven't seen any WildFly code, but that is not possible with CMS (container-managed security). The element `auth-method` is singular, not plural.

You have to peform a hybrid authentication which supports SPNEGO and then falls back to form auth. But this will be very tricky because how do you know that the client has not provided a SPNEGO ticket? You have to maintain a per connection state for this and redirect to the form. If you send a form upfront with the `WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate` then client will never re-retrieve your resource and your form won't kick it b/c SPNEGO has kicked it.

I would recommend against and combine `Negotiate` with `Basic`. This is little/less headache.